# Where to place my jest mock when testing useMutation in RTK Query?

Tags: ts-jest, rtk-query

I have a custom hook where I am using the function below:

```
const [getApiCall, { isError: apiError }] =
    useGetApiCallMutation();//useMutation from rtk query
async function Test() {
    try {
      const response = await getApiCall.unwrap();

      if (response.details) {
        console.log("success")
        setAdmin(prev => [...prev, ...existing]);
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

I have written the jest test below:

```
const mockResponse = {
  details: [
    { userUuid: '1', rank: 'Rank1', name: 'User1' },
    { userUuid: '2', rank: 'Rank2', name: 'User2' }
  ]
};

describe('unit testing', () => {
  jest.mock('Queries/pathToApi', () => ({
    useAddAdminSupportMutation: () => [
      async () => ({
        unwrap: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse)
      }),

      { isError: false }
    ],
    useGetAdminSupportsMutation: () => [
      async () => ({
        unwrap: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse)
      }),

      { isError: false }
    ]
  }));

  const wrapper = ({ children }: any) => {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  };

  test('should call correct functions', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useAddAdminSupport(true, jest.fn, 1), {
      wrapper
    });

    await act(async () => {
      await result.current.getAllAdminSupport();
    });
  });
});
```

If I put the jest.mock outside the describe block it will result in TypeError: Cannot read property 'reducerPath' of undefined but if I put the jest.mock inside the describe block but outside of the test case, it will try to call the actual baseQuery API, How can I mock the uuseGetApiCallMutation properly without using another third party package like msw?
Another question I have is how to test for the change in useState e.g. setAdmin(prev => [...prev, ...existing]);